# Counting instances across 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a formula which counts the total number of instances across two columns.  Image 1 appeared four times but was labelled a cat three times.  I am looking for a formula that will generate the correct answer in cell e2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NhBw.png)

Comment: You're looking for `COUNTIFS`

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two solutions. One is easier to understand but uses a helper column with A and B contant concattenated. Then we use a simple COUNTIF searching for that key.

[image: Screenshot of excel with all formula's shown]

Alternatively, as can add an extra 'S' to the countif command and get the much cleaner, but alos more complex solution like below.
[image]

To be fair, taking the name "Dat" and "Dog" from E1 and F1 might be pushing it a bit to far for maintainable code.